# C# VSIX-Templates: Trying to use a custom wizard results into an assembly reference error

Tags: c#, templates, .net-assembly, vsix

I've been getting into C# item and project templates.

I followed Microsoft's documentation on how to make a custom Wizard, but whenever I try to use the item template that I have made, I run into an error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2019

The item template works, when I don't reference the WizardExtension tags in the vstemplate of the template, but that defeats my whole point of using tags and a wizard for pre-written code.

Could someone help me figure out why that is? I will include the files in case someone wants to try it for themselves or even help to correct them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wizard assembly is not strong-named. If you strong-name the assembly, and use the fullname of the assembly in your  tag, I suspect that'll fix you up.

I wrote a blog entry that was subsequently archived detailing how to do this, which is now located at :

[Creating a VSIX Deployable Project (or Item) Template with Custom Wizard Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsx/creating-a-vsix-deployable-project-or-item-template-with-custom-wizard-support)

The first time you build the signed assembly, you'll need to retrieve it's PublicTokenKey, to fix up the  tag in your .vstemplate. The following article shows how to add a custom tool to your Tools menu to easily retrieve that token string:

[How to: Create a Tool to Get the Public Key of an Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539398(v=office.14))

Also, you don't need that Package.cs file. But if you remove it, be sure you set the project's "Generate .pkgdef File" property to false, so you don't get a build error trying to generate a .pkgdef, and remove the corresponding Package asset from your .vsixmanifest.

Comment: Turns out that the order mattered a lot too. I had to sign the assembly and then add it to the manifest, which solved the issue for me. Additionally, I don't know why, but directly changing the project file was also a factor.